# PHP: sort ZIP in alphabetical order

Tags: php, sorting, zip

The following PHP file creates a ZIP File and works as it should.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$ZIP_name = "./path/Prefix_" .$date . ".zip";

if ($zip->open($ZIP_name, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("There is a ZIP Error");
} 
if ($zip->open($ZIP_name, ZipArchive::CREATE)==TRUE) {
    echo "ZIP File can be created" . "<br>";
} 

foreach($list as $element) {
    $path_and_filename = "../path_to_somewhere/product_" 
                       . $element 
                       . ".csv";
    $zip->addFile($path_and_filename, basename($path_and_filename));
}
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";  // number of element files
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";       // Status "0" = okay

$zip->close();
?>
```

There is only a small blemish:
The above foreach-loop retrieves elements from an array where all elements are sorted in alphabetical order. After the ZIP-File creation, the files within the ZIP are in different order, maybe caused by different file size.

Is there a way to sort the csv files within the ZIP with PHP later on? I'm new to ZIP creation with PHP an I have not found something helpful in the documentation.

Comment: Do you trying to sort files in the file system? Why you want to do that? o_O

Comment: I just want to do that to make it beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, better just sort the file list in your program, not in the file system (-;